# erro texto flutuar ao lado imagem html

Tags: html5, css3

Galera e o seginte esta ocorrendo um erro e eu n consigo resolve-lo o texto esta colado na imagem, eu queria que pelo menos tivesse algum espaço entre o texto e a imagem,

ja tentei colocar margin-left e n vai estou usando bootstrap e o codigo esta asim

```css
#skill1 {
}



#skill1 img{
 width:200px;
 background-color:#F60;
 float:left;
 
 
}


#skill1 p {
 text-align:left;
 margin-top:5%;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="container-fluid">



<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="skill1">



<img src="img/html.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">




<p> Até algum tempo atrás, as animações nos sites eram feitas javascript ou flash. Com o surgimento do CSS 3 essa ideia vem mudando.

As animações com CSS dão um show de performance, são mais fluidas e sem travamentos. Como nem tudo são rosas, elas só funcionam em navegadores mais modernos. E aí que se encaixa o Graceful Degradation.

Em navegadores antigos, que não suportam essas animações, apresentamos o mesmo conteúdo, porém de uma maneira diferente sem perder nada em relação à acessibilidade.</p>

</div>






</div>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente dar uma margem na imagem usando `margin: 10px`. Veja:

```
.img-responsive {
  margin: 10px
}
```

```css
#skill1 {
}

#skill1 img{
 width:200px;
 background-color:#F60;
 float:left; 
}

#skill1 p {
 text-align:left;
 margin-top:5%;  
}

.img-responsive {
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="skill1">
         <img src="img/html.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
         <p> Até algum tempo atrás, as animações nos sites eram feitas javascript ou flash. Com o surgimento do CSS 3 essa ideia vem mudando.
            As animações com CSS dão um show de performance, são mais fluidas e sem travamentos. Como nem tudo são rosas, elas só funcionam em navegadores mais modernos. E aí que se encaixa o Graceful Degradation.
            Em navegadores antigos, que não suportam essas animações, apresentamos o mesmo conteúdo, porém de uma maneira diferente sem perder nada em relação à acessibilidade.
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Edição

Esta edição é para responder a pergunta feita nos comentários, para que o texto permaneça abaixo da imagem sem margem pela esquerda, em casos de telas menores.

```css
.areaImagem{
    float:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    background: #ccc;
    
}

.areaImagem img{
    display: inline-blcok;
   width: 200px;
    margin:2%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.areaTexto p{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin:2%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="skill1">
        <div class="areaImagem">
          <img src="img/html.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
         <div class="areaTexto">
         <p class="text"> Até algum tempo atrás, as animações nos sites eram feitas javascript ou flash. Com o surgimento do CSS 3 essa ideia vem mudando.
            As animações com CSS dão um show de performance, são mais fluidas e sem travamentos. Como nem tudo são rosas, elas só funcionam em navegadores mais modernos. E aí que se encaixa o Graceful Degradation.
            Em navegadores antigos, que não suportam essas animações, apresentamos o mesmo conteúdo, porém de uma maneira diferente sem perder nada em relação à acessibilidade.
         </p>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pera ai que eu vou ali da um tiro na minha cabeça....

pqp fiquei horas travado nesse erro bobo tentei 10000 de coisas e nada dava certo e agora eu vi que algo tao simples e bobo resolveu meu problema,

mais enfim eu ja esperava que a solução para isso era algo simples que eu ntava acertando

Comment: no caso tem uma maneira de mover somente o bloco de texto? pq quando coloco margin move o bloco com a imagem tbm

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara relaxa, é a cama chamando pra ir logo. hehehe

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara mover como? não entendi

Comment: quando eu aplico margin:10px a imagem tbm move dando um margin entre a imagem e a div, conseguiu resolver o meu problema, porem tem uma maneira de so o bloco de texto se mover?

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara você pode colocar um margin-left: 240px no seu <p>.. Ai esse valor seria o espaço da imagem. Caso não queira fazer assim, teria que reestruturar suas divs.

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara fiz um teste aqui colocando margin-left no <p>  funcionou. Qualquer dúvida estou por aqui.

Comment: o problema e que margin-left no p o texto n fica responsivo e quando cai para o tamanho de tela pequeno a imagem fica no centro e o texto fica com left para a direita

Comment: @FernandoAlcantara editei a questão, colocando o que você precisava. Espero que seja isso. Qualquer coisa, dê um toque aqui.